# How to add content above footer in posts from specific category

Tags: posts, functions, categories, get-posts, footer

I want to add “custom footer” above default footer to posts for specific category

I have function that works, but that "custom footer" also appears on the archive category pages which I don’t want but only on its posts.

*( I don’t want CSS - display: none; )*

My function:

```
function your_function() { 
if (in_category(array ('cars' , 'trucks' ))) { // Category ID
 echo '<p class="plus-footer">Custom content to insert</p>';
 }
}
add_action('get_footer', 'your_function');
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried adding "is_singular()" to your test?

Comment: @Jeff Cohan

Yes, I tried.

I got the solution from PHP master

- if (is_single() && in_category(array ('cars' , 'trucks' ))) { -

Thanks for your response.

Comment: And did that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, that's solution